# displaying tags in a widget

Tags: widgets, tags

I have a widget which displays the latest projects as thumbnails on my website.
When I mouse over a thumbnail the project title appears; 
this is the code  for title:

`<h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>`

So, I'm thinking to display also  the tags from that specific project, to be something like 
 beautiful, nature, landscape

Is this possible, or could you give me some suggestions on how to achieve this ? 
Thanks!

Comment: does http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags not do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what code you've posted, it seems like you've got a secondary loop set up (using a `WP_Query` object). So to display the current' posts tags you can use:

- [`the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) - to print a  list of the post's tags
- [`wp_tag_cloud`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) - to print a tag cloud.
- [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)  - to return an array of tag objects, which you can then use to display the tags however you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Tags can be shown outside the **Post loop** using the global functions.

Step 1 : Get a [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) (this solved many problems)

Step 2 : Place the Code `<?php the_tags(); ?>` in widget and Save.

Check [Tags Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) to tweak display order.